# Git clone using ssh has a timeout

Tags: git, bash, ssh, vpn

Hi guys I would just like to share some of my problem on git. I have been cloning on different unit and all of them were successful. But now I have encounter on a unit that would not let me clone or even pull.

here is there error:

> ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection timed out fatal:
>   The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I already tried two different way on cloning a repository.

1st

> git clone ssh://username@ip.com/~/linuxLink.git

2nd

first I go to an empty folder using git bash.

> git init -> to initialize a repository
>
> git remote -v - just to make sure the remotes are empty
>
> git remote add origin ssh://username@ip.com/~/linuxLink.git
>
> git pull
>
> ssh: connect to host 162.144.35.182.ipage.com port 22: Connection timed out
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I also notice after I install git bash when I go to C:/user/pcname/ I cannot see .ssh the other unit has it.

can someone please tell me where did I go wrong.
thank you so much.

Comment: There is a similar question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172188/ssh-server-connect-to-host-xxx-port-22-connection-timed-out-on-linux-ubuntu 
Try the solution given there and see if it works for you..

Comment: hi Vivek thanks for helping me on my issue but I also tried it. We are all on the same network. Sorry I also did not say I did not reach the part where I need to put a password.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you say `ssh://username@ip.com` you mean something like `ssh://typecasto@123.203.23.32`, right? `ssh://typecasto@123.203.23.32.com` isn't going to work, it's going to try to resolve that address through DNS. Also, can you connect to the host through SSH in general? i.e. running `ssh username@ip` works? If not, that may indicate a portforwarding issue.