# timeout when I try to ssh cpanel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, cpanel

I am trying to connect to the C panel server through ssh but I get a timeout.

**What I have tried**

I have tried *ssh user@domain.com* and user@ipaddress to no avail
 I already tried using the ftp user account but the result is the same. I don't know what to do.

**The goal**

I have to connect in order to install rails on the server and this is a huge delay.
 Please help.

the error is 
ssh: connect to host xxx.co.ke port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: This seems to be a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172188/ssh-server-connect-to-host-xxx-port-22-connection-timed-out-on-linux-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible reasons for this.

1. SSH is not configured on this port
2. SSH is not enabled on this server
3. The firewall on your server is blocking your IP

We will need more information like are you having a VPS or a shared hosting plan as many hosting companies do not allow ssh in shared hosting plans. If this is a VPS then you will need to ask your hosting provider the SSH port and try. Are you able to ping your server IP. If not, then you will also need to check in the server firewall if your IP is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong SSH port OR your ISP ip is blocked on your server and due to that you are getting connection time out, You need to confirm your SSH server port from your hosting provider and ask them to enable SSH access for your cPanel user.