# Why do I get this error while running rsync?

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to transfer my file from localhost to server using **rsync**. But this is what happens

```
abc@abc_def:~$ rsync -v -e ssh textfile.txt
abc@123.45.67.890:/home/test
ssh: connect to host 123.45.67.890 port 22: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
abc@abc_def:~$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh server connect to host xxx port 22: Connection timed out on linux-ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172188/ssh-server-connect-to-host-xxx-port-22-connection-timed-out-on-linux-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops there was a mistake in the command just now i had cleared and it working now.

> rsync -av -P -e 'ssh -p 1111' text.txt  abc@123.45.67.890:/home/abc