# ssh timed out - how to create ssh_config file?

Tags: ssh, connection-timeout

I have the exact same problem as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335069/vscode-remote-connection-error-the-process-tried-to-write-to-a-nonexistent-pipe) question. A couple of days ago, I could solve it by deleting the `known_hosts` file as described in some of the answers in the linked question.

However, today I encountered the supposedly same problem but the above method did not help. I realized that I also get a timed out error, when I want to open the ssh connection directly in the prompt (I'm using Win10 locally, but the remote machine runs on Linux).

When I run

```
C:\Users\user>ssh -vvv user@Host
```

I get the following output:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for Host
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "Host" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to Host [some ip] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:00000190EA383690
debug1: connect to address some ip port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to Host [address] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:00000190EA383690
debug1: connect to address address port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host Host port 22: Connection timed out
```

I checked the `/ProgramData/ssh` folder and realized that there is no ssh_config file. Do I have to set up this file manually? If yes, how does this work? Or is it possible to run some command in order to create it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was ridiculously easy. I forgot to turn on the VPN required to establish a connection to the host. Sometimes there seem to be very easy solutions to such an issue as e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172188/ssh-server-connect-to-host-xxx-port-22-connection-timed-out-on-linux-ubuntu), where one only had to turn off an on one's internet router...